# Why does PHPUnit in a GitHub workflow generate different test coverage XML report compared to local?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, clover, codecov

I am running a code coverage workflow in GitHub action for [this PHP package](https://github.com/DataLinx/gettext-context) and it generates a different XML report than the one I get when I run the PHPUnit tests locally, resulting in lower coverage score.

Here is the workflow file:

```yml
name: Update codecov

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

env:
  LANG: "sl_SI.utf8"

jobs:
  codecov:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Set up system locale
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y locales
          sudo locale-gen ${{ env.LANG }}

      - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
        run: composer validate --strict

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: 7.2
          extensions: xdebug, gettext

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress --prefer-stable

      - name: Run test suite
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit

      - name: Upload to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
          files: ./build/coverage.xml
          verbose: true
```

Locally I get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1673717717">
  <project timestamp="1673717717">
    <file name="/app/src/gettext-context.php">
      <line num="13" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="15" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="18" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="20" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="23" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="39" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="40" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="42" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="45" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="47" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="50" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="65" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="67" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="70" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="72" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="75" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="92" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="93" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="95" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="98" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="100" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="103" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <metrics loc="105" ncloc="55" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="22" coveredstatements="22" elements="22" coveredelements="22"/>
    </file>
    <metrics files="1" loc="105" ncloc="55" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="22" coveredstatements="22" elements="22" coveredelements="22"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

However, the XML that is uploaded by the workflow to codecov.io is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1673722112">
  <project timestamp="1673722112">
    <file name="/home/runner/work/gettext-context/gettext-context/src/gettext-context.php">
      <line num="3" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="13" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="15" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="18" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="20" type="stmt" count="3"/>
      <line num="23" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="27" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="39" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="40" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="42" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="45" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="47" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="50" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="54" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="65" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="67" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="70" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="72" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="75" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="79" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="92" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="93" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="95" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="98" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="100" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <line num="103" type="stmt" count="1"/>
      <metrics loc="105" ncloc="55" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="26" coveredstatements="22" elements="26" coveredelements="22"/>
    </file>
    <metrics files="1" loc="105" ncloc="55" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="26" coveredstatements="22" elements="26" coveredelements="22"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

Since the second one contains lines with supposedly no coverage (e.g. `<line num="3" type="stmt" count="0"/>`), my codecov result is 86 % instead of 100 % like in local.

The lines in questions are `if (function_exits('some_function'))` statements seen in the [source file](https://github.com/DataLinx/gettext-context/blob/master/src/gettext-context.php). They simply assert that the function does not exist before declaring it.
[Here's](https://app.codecov.io/gh/DataLinx/gettext-context/blob/master/src/gettext-context.php) how it looks in codecov.

I have zero ideas why the XML reports are different. Both environments are running the same PHP version and dev. dependencies. The `phpunit.dist.xml` file is the same for both cases and it's being respected, since otherwise the test would fail, considering the bootstrap file is only defined in the `phpunit.dist.xml` file.

Comment: You may want to add a test to your testsuite that asserts the gettext extension is loaded and enabled. Equally important assert that you have not loaded the file with the conditional function definitions prior the test that looks for the coverage as both your testsuite and your coverage gathering depends on it. This can be done to check whether the (first) function already exists - but must not - and additionally (but a bit more weak) if the file is already within [`get_included_files()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) - but must not.

Comment: @hakre gettext is already a dependency in composer.json, so I see no need to check whether it's still available? Considering tests are run by developers only.
I tried but I honestly don't understand the second point :) Loading the file is not a feature of the package so it's not being tested. The conditionals are being executed so they are also covered by the test.

Comment: Yes, this also was my first thought, however I was unsure if in the one setup composer is not involved (e.g. phpunit called directly but composer loading already done and therefore functions already defined _before_ gathering the coverage). I don't 100% know, but it kinda smelled that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% understanding what's going on, but I fixed it.
I did two things:

1. Using the codecov official reference article for PHP that is available [here](https://about.codecov.io/blog/measuring-php-code-coverage-with-phpunit-and-github-actions/), I updated my workflow to match their's and ended up with the following:

```yml
name: Update codecov

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

env:
  LANG: "sl_SI.utf8"

jobs:
  codecov:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Set up system locale
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y locales
          sudo locale-gen ${{ env.LANG }}

      - name: Install composer and dependencies
        uses: php-actions/composer@v6
        with:
          php_extensions: gettext

      - name: PHPUnit Tests
        uses: php-actions/phpunit@v3
        env:
          XDEBUG_MODE: coverage
        with:
          configuration: phpunit.xml.dist
          php_extensions: gettext xdebug
          args: --coverage-clover ./coverage.xml

      - name: Upload to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
          files: ./coverage.xml
          verbose: true
```

2. I moved the all the recommended settings from php.ini to phpunit.xml(.dist), since obviously they are not being used by the GH action, unless in phpunit.xml.

```xml
    <php>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="On"/>
        <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On"/>
        <!--
            PHPUnit recommended PHP config
            https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/installation.html#recommended-php-configuration
        -->
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="log_errors_max_len" value="0"/>
        <ini name="zend.assertions" value="1"/>
        <ini name="assert.exception" value="1"/>
        <ini name="xdebug.show_exception_trace" value="0"/>
    </php>
```

This fixed it and the Clover XML file generated remotely perfectly matches the local (dev) one. I was therefore able to achieve 100 % coverage :)

Comment: It's either a "not" is missing or the "but" should be an "and" (first sentence). ^^ --- Wondering if you don't want to add a loader class that can be psr-4 autoloaded so you can give easier access to enable the functions at runtime. Then a user of your package must not fiddle with its own composer.json config and hard-encode the name of the vendor folder (which at the end of the day is not controlled by composer.json but composer itself).

Comment: @hakre ah yes, it should have been "I'm not 100%" :)
PSR-4 is for classes only, right? AFAIK there's no autoloader for functions? So you are trying to say the functions should be moved to static methods in a "helper" class? I personally don't like that pattern.

Comment: Yes, no autoloader for functions, but for classes. This you can make use of. E.g. either one utility class only with a single static method that when called does the require_once and you have it in composer PSR-4, and/or you implement the functions as well as static methods and keep the global function names calling the static methods implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will consider it :) Especially since it's backwards compatible and lets the developer choose how they want to load the package functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your clear use-case (the library under test is a single file) and also the well written question, it can be answered *how* the code coverage differed:

- If the functions have already been defined before the code-coverage is gathered and also from a different file (not that one under test), the actual lines of the functions are not covered.
- If the functions are undefined, they will be covered by the code-coverage, not only their `if` clauses.

Albeit this is clear to say in an answer, we also may tend to ask then *why* that was the case, however your question shows too little information so that doing so would tend to speculation.

However from what I know the difference is not explained by using a different code-coverage mechanism, e.g. xdebug vs. pcov, which is another common reason for different coverage, however on a much more detailed level. It is also not xdebug 2 vs. xdebug 3, as you're using PHP 7.2 which only has xdebug 2 (and btw. the PHP version conflicts to what you merchandise the package for: >= 7.4 - obviously that is not a requirement but fake [not a moral judgement]).

I'd recommend you double check the requirements in an automated test so that you don't blindly run the whole-testsuite only to find out in coverage later on, that the code you expected to be covered was not at all (while the test suite reported differently, tending to be fake as well [not a moral judgement again, just saying]).  This could be done by asserting the return value of the `require_once` call in bootstrap.php already, then running phpunit with php assertions active & throwing (which is recommended for running PHP for tests in PHP 7.0+).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments :) // Regarding PHP versions, in the mean time I bumped the requirement to 7.4, since support for 7.2 and 7.3 was dropped a long time ago, but 7.4 only recently. The requirement is there because of the dev. dependencies. // Before I wrote this question I got same results in 7.2 and 8.1. // You wrote a lot of points which are not clear to me (sorry!), but stack's comments are very limiting, so if you are still interested, you're welcome to post in the package GH discussions, which I just activated, and I'll do my best to improve the package.

Comment: I guess you're commenting about the part with the composer autoloader / utility to not depend on require/_once ? Please elaborate, because I think that is something your utility library can benefit from. I could outline and/or elaborate as well directly in a pull request and having an issue for discussion.

Comment: I understand your point regarding the improvement for loading the functions. In this thread I commented your other points and pointed out I don't quite understand some of them, so the invitation to move to GH still stands, considering my original problem is no longer relevant :)